# access localstorage before page loads - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, local-storage

I want to access the localstorage of a browser before a page loads.
For the first time i set the localstorage like

```
  value = $(this).data("style")
  localStorage.setItem("style_id", value);
```

next time the page loads, i need to load the value stored in localstorage.

So lets say when page loads in controller particular action is called

```
def page
  call(style_id)   #by default i use style.first.syle_id
end
```

so i want to pass the local storage value to the call function before page loads

Comment: I don't think this is possible. A more sensible way of storing this would be in the session hash.

Comment: @Slicedpan Thanks, i'll try storing in seesionstorage